# Cannot login in Php MySQL android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make an app which has remember log in feature, which mean if user  has logged into my app, he do not need to login again. I refer this [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-login-example-using-php-mysql-and-volley/)

But the problem is I getting `invalid username or password` message even though I fill in  the correct name and password. Have I missed anything ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
 private void login(final String username, final String password) {

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Configs.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //If we are getting success from server
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(Configs.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                            //Creating a shared preference
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Configs.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putBoolean(Configs.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(Configs.NAME_SHARED_PREF, username);

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.commit();

                            //Starting profile activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //You can handle error here if you want
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put(Configs.KEY_USER_NAME, username);
                params.put(Configs.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

**Configs**

```
    public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
    public static final String NAME_SHARED_PREF = "name";
```

**Php**

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "select * from users where name='$username' and password='$password'";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

 if(isset($check)){
 echo "success";
 }else{
 echo "Invalid Username or Password";
 }

 }else{
 echo "error try again";
 }
```

I had implemented another login function and using the same url

```
  private void login(final String username, String password) {

        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Please Wait",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomePage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name",username);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("username", params[0]);
                data.put("password",params[1]);

                RequestHandler ruc = new RequestHandler();

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(Configs.LOGIN_URL,data);

                return result;
            }
        }
        UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
        ulc.execute(username, password);
    }
```

It works. But if I change the code to  `SharedPreferences`, it does not work.

Comment: check password is stored in `md5` format?

Comment: @PathikVejani no, I store password in varchar datatype

Comment: yes it should be in varchar, but see is it encrypted or not?

Comment: run url with parameter in browser if its works means check android side

Comment: also check what comes in `$cehck`?

Comment: Check whether $username and $password has expected values!

Comment: @sasikumar check my edited.

Comment: @PathikVejani check my post again

Comment: @uglypointer check my post again

Comment: Storing username and password on the device is pretty bad practive. Look at oauth authentication and only store a unique token on the phone that can be revoked on the server.

Comment: And please, don't store the passwords as clear text in your database. Only store a a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,I have solved it.

The `Configs.KEY_USER_NAME` should be equal to `username` , but I defined it as `name` in `Configs` class .

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 $con = new database ("localhost","username","password","database");


 $sql = "select * from users where name='$username' and password='$password'";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

 if(isset($check)){
 echo "success";
 }else{
 echo "Invalid Username or Password";
 }

 }else{
 echo "error try again";
 }
```

please call your database class like `$con = new yourclass name("localhost","username","password","database");`

Comment: But if I using another login code, the php works fine

Answer (score 1):

Check android side by charles ,check the php side by Chrome's Postman(Post mothod) and check the Mysql by sql phrase.